# Entra ID and SCIM: Setting up enum attribute for request to API

Tags: attributes, okta, scim, entra

For the company I work for, I've set up some endpoints for SCIM usage.  Right now most of our clients are using Okta.  Recently I've beend tasked with doing a POC for Entra ID provisioning so we can have documentation on how to set it up.
In Okta you can set an integer array for a custom attribute, then define IN Okta what integers are available as well as what they correspond to. The problem I'm running into is that Entra doesn't seem to have this same feature.  You can set the attribute as an individual value like an integer or string OR you can set it as an expression but thats it.  Also note that in the Okta setup, I'm not mapping the attribute to anything other than the explicit list of integers that the provisioner can choose from.

I've included an image of how the attribute is setup in Okta for reference.[Working Okta Attribute Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEbpx.png)

So far I've been trying to form an expression in Entra to get the job done, but haven't had much luck.  I'm unsure if this is because doing it as an expression is the incorrect approach of if I just don't know that much about how their expressions work.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. The closest you'll get is assigning roles in the Users and Groups blade on the app, but that only is intended to map to the "roles" attribute in SCIM.

Comment: Is it possible to map the attribute "Permission" to roles via an expression?

Comment: I'm not aware of any attribute called "Permission" in the AAD/Entra schema. Is this a custom attribute you've defined in a schema on the SCIM app?